# TextWriterTraceListener creating multiple files with crazy names

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I have using the System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener for degbugging my app. It's been appending a lot of files any it gets called.

[image]

I deally I like to have only the trace outputs appened to a single file such as Trace-[Todays current date].text

Heres a could snippet of the problem code

```
  public static void SendDebug(string message, string category)
    {
        if ((ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Debug"] != null) && (ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Debug"].ToUpper() == "VERBOSE"))
        {
            var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Trace-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt";

            TextWriterTraceListener[] listeners = new TextWriterTraceListener[] {
        new TextWriterTraceListener(path, "myListener") };
            Trace.Listeners.AddRange(listeners);

            Trace.TraceInformation(message, category);
            Trace.Flush();
            Trace.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Everytime you call `SendDebug` a new listener is created and added. And I don't find an overload of `TraceInformation` with two strings.

Comment: Thanks shingo i see my error i believe have multiple trace listeners was culprit and your also correct about TraceInformation somehow it think its be casting string to a object[] since wasnt getting a runtime error